# Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be events such that $A$ and $B$ are independent, $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive.

Tags: probability, statistics

I need to find $P((A \cap B)' \cup C)$ where $P(A) = 1/4$, $P(B) = 1/6$, and $P(C) = 1/2$.

I know $P(A \cap B)' = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) + P(C) = 1/4 + 1/6 - 1/24 + 1/2 = 21/24$
But how do I do the union $C$ part? $C$ is disjoint from everything else, so If I add $1/2$ or $12/24$ again I will be adding $C$ twice. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $B$ and $C$ are mutually exclusive, then $A \cap B$ and $C$ are also mutually exclusive. So $C \subset (A \cap B)'$. So do you need to add $P(C)$ or any part of it at all?

Comment: i know c is sub set of everything not in a and b but how do i add that to my 21/24

Comment: ohhh so my answer is correct without adding c! is that what youre saying?

Comment: indeed :) that's the nasty trick they pulled in the problem

Comment: well miracle173 just told me something different. are we right or are they?

Comment: THe other answer is giving different numbers but the reasoning is the same as what I gave, in terms of that $P(C)$ doesn't matter because $C \subset (A \cap B)'$. So your answer should just be $P((A \cap B)')$

Answer (score 1):

$$P(A \cap B) = P(A )P(B)=\frac{1}{4}  \frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{24} $$
because $A$ and $B$ are independent. 
So
$$P(A \cap B)' = 1 - P(A \cap B)=\frac{23}{24}$$ This is a well known [law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axioms_of_probability#More_consequences) of probability theory.

The rest is set theory.   $B$ and $C$ are mutual exclusive, so $B \cap C = \emptyset$. We get  $(A \cap B) \cap C =\emptyset$ an therefore $(A \cap B)' \supseteq C$ . So 
$(A \cap B)' \cup C =(A \cap B)'$ and $P((A ∩ B)'∪ C)=P((A ∩ B)')=\frac{23}{24}$

Comment: this is completely different. am i not right at all then?

Comment: @dee: I don't understand P(A ∩ B)' = P(A) + P(B) - P(A ∩ B) + P(C)